# Correlation Recorder is not picking up all the traffic

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I was attempting to use a correlation recorder from blazemeter, but encountered a couple problems.

The page I'm trying to access redirects it self to a new resource/page (303 and 307 response codes) and for some reason the recorder does not pick up anything after that.

I read the documentation and found this section

```
- Disable redirect disabling: Set the proxy.redirect.disabling property to false in your user.properties file. This is required for a proper and automatic correlation experience.
    
- Set deflate mode: If you plan to record in Siebel CRM environments, set the httpclient4.deflate_relax_mode property to true in your user.properties file. This will help you avoid Unexpected end of input stream errors.
    
- (Optional) Set the scope of post-processors to all: Set the Sample.scope property to all in your user.properties file. This will help you to avoid the post-processors to only limit to the main sampler.
```

I didn't see it in my user.properties so I assumed that I should just add it in there if it wasn't present. It still didn't seem to change anything when I tried recording again.

The weird thing is that when I stopped recording and started recording at the spot it redirects me to it picks up the information again for a bit then stops.

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Correlation Recorder won't add anything to *user.properties* file, any configuration amendments are up to you
2. Make sure to **restart JMeter** after each change to any *user.properties* file, it's required so JMeter would read the file and apply the changes

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)
- also check out [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) for better understanding of how Post-Processors placement in the Test Plan affects their actions